# XML parsing problem

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm having this strange XML parsing problem.

I have this XML string I'm trying to parse

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response status="success">
<lot>32342</lot>
</response>
```

I'm using XPath with Java in order to do this. I'm using the Xpath expression "/response/@status" to find the text "success". However whenever I evaluate this expression I get an empty string.

However I am able to successfully parse this string using "/response/@type"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response type="success">
<lot>32342</lot>
</response>
```

So why would simply changing the name of the attribute change the return string to nothing?

```
is = new InputSource(new StringReader(testWOcreateStrGood)); 
xPathexpressionSuccess = xPath.compile("/response/@status");
responseStr = xPathexpressionSuccess.evaluate(is);
```

reponseStr is the string I posted earlier with the "status" attribute

Also I declared testWOcreateStrGood as below

```
    private String testWOcreateStrGood = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +
                            "<response status=\"success\">\n" +
                            "<lot>32342</lot>\n" +
                            "</response>";
```

Comment: Can you post some quick and dirty sample code? This could be a problem with the code you are using :)

Answer (score 1):

*So why would simply changing the name of the attribute change the return string to nothing?*

It shouldn't. You must be doing something else wrong, e.g. accessing the wrong XML document or not actually using the XPath expression you believe to be using.

---

To your code example:

Check the API documentation for `InputSource`. You cannot pass an XML document as a string directly to the constructor.

Comment: As an addition, a quick clean/recompile would be a good idea, and check the paths - maybe dump the xml to the System.out or a log?

Comment: And in your code now, you're using XPath to access the "status" attribute of an XML document with a "type" attribute. That is of course not going to work. It's not very easy to help you if you're not even able to ask a plain question without creating such a mess.

Comment: I apologize I've been going crazy with this code for a while now